# Excel Power Query - Sorting/Filtering Table

Tags: sql, excel, sorting, filtering, powerquery

I am using Power Query to pull data from a SQL database into Excel as a simple table.

The intent of this is to record comments in a manual column (not part of the SQL database) for the various records pulled into the table, and then refresh the table week-over-week to get updated data for each record but maintain the comments from previous weeks.

I was able to successfully write the query and retrieve the data, but whenever I *sort* the data and then refresh the query, my manually added comments become misaligned.

I have checked the "Preserve column sort/filter/layout" option on the External Data Properties window for the query, and *filtering* seems to work fine (if I only filter and add manual comments, refreshing the dataset does not alter the placement of the comments) and yet *sorting* does not work.

When the SQL query is run, the records are sorted by a key column (wherein the value for each record is unique), but I cannot find a way in the Power Query editor to force the refreshed data to align to this field.

Example per Wedge's Response:

Step 1. Execute SQL Query
[image: SQL Data Query]

Step 2. Add manual comment
[image: Manual Comment]

Step 3. Sort differently than original query (not same as ORDER BY)
[image: Sort Differently]

Step 4. Refresh the original SQL Query
[image: SQL Query Refresh]

As you can see in the example, the "Test" comment is aligned to a different PurchaseOrderLineID after I refreshed the SQL Query.

I have attempted to create a "From Table" query (from my SQL output table) and Merge that with my original SQL query as seen below, but I am still having the same issue.
[image: Merge Query]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rows you are importing all have a way to uniquely identify them (which coming out of a SQL table I would think this is the case) then you can use that to keep your comments aligned. Go to your output table in Excel, use "From Table" on the PQ menu, and make it a connection only Query.

Then go to your original Query that is pulling from the SQL database and add a "Merge Queries" step against the table you just loaded in (which will have your comment column). Merge them based on whatever uniquely identifies the rows and expand only the comment column from the merge.

This way whenever you refresh your table, it will match and retain any existing comments before updating the output table in Excel.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I understand the logic behind your response, but I am still running into some issue - if I add a comment to the first row of the original output table (from the SQL database query) and refresh my "From Table" query, the comment appears in the secondary table aligned to the correct unique identifier.  Once I sort the original output table (i.e. so the comment is now on the bottom) and then refresh the SQL database query, the comment jumps back to the top of the table (aligned to the wrong unique identifier).  Could this be fixed with the refresh order?

Comment: The From Table query should not be loading back into the workbook. If it is, just delete the sheet it is on and it will let you keep it as a "Connection Only" query.

Comment: I think I figured it out thanks to your steps.  The key was to 'trick' the merge step into overwriting the "Comments" field from the original SQL Query table with the field from the "From Table" query (that was then merged).  It is still doing something strange in terms of sorting (the unique identifiers move into a different order after sorting and then refreshing), but nothing detrimental and the comments stay aligned to the correct unique identifier.

Comment: Oh yeah, I assumed there was no comments field coming from the SQL query since it was something you were manually typing in Excel. A merge operation in PQ is probably going to mess with the default sort order coming form the SQL statement, so I would just add a sort operation after the merge in PQ if you want it to be sorted a specific way on refresh.